# Issue with kendo, no data in the grid

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I've been looking for this since days now ! So i hope someone could help.

It's a big project so i can't put it all here but if you need more code just tell me and i will add it.

So i have a grid that should contains what's inside my database. But instead i got a k-no-data, can't figure out why.

There is my grid :

```
<section id="main-content">
<section class="wrapper site-min-height">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-10 main-chart">
            <div class="border-head">
                <h3>Results</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-3 col-sm-12">
                <div class="showback">
                    <h4>Text example</h4>
                    <div class="panel panel-info">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            @(Html.Kendo().Grid<DisplayGridResultatsPrestations>
                                ()
                                .Name("GridListeIdcc")
                                .Columns(columns =>
                                {
                                    columns.Bound(c => c.CategoriePrestation);
                                    columns.Bound(c => c.DesignationPrestation);
                                    columns.Bound(c => c.ValeurPreconisee);
                                    columns.Bound(c => c.ValeurProposee);
                                    columns.Bound(c => c.DesignationResultat);
                                })
                                .Filterable()
                                .Selectable(selectable => selectable.Mode(GridSelectionMode.Single).Type(GridSelectionType.Row))
                                .DataSource(datasource => datasource
                                .Ajax()
                                .Read(reader => reader.Action("THISISCONFIDENTIAL", "Comparaison", new { identifiantResultatsComparaison }))
                                .Model(model =>
                                {
                                    model.Id("Id");
                                })
                                .Group(group => group.Add(c => c.SOMETHINGCONFIDENTIALTOO))
                                .ServerOperation(true)))
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

```
function onSelection(arg) 
{
    var grid = $("#GridListeIdcc").data("kendoGrid");
    var selectedItem = grid.dataItem(grid.select());
}
```

So i think it should work, but nothing happen i just have a header on my grid with title but no value.

I know it's not really clear but if i miss something important i think you will tell.

```
public JsonResult THISICONFIDENTIAL([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request,
        string identifiantResultatsComparaison)
    {
        var resultats = _resultatComparaisonService.FindResultatById(identifiantResultatsComparaison);

        var listePrestations = resultats.ListeDesPrestationsApresComparaison;
        List<DisplayGridResultatsPrestations> diplayListeResultats = listePrestations.Select(prestation => new DisplayGridResultatsPrestations
        {
            CCN = prestation.NomAccordSante + " (" + prestation.IdentifiantAccordSante + ")",
            IdentifiantAccord = prestation.IdentifiantAccordSante,
            CategoriePrestation = prestation.CategoriePrestation,
            NomPrestation = prestation.NomPrestation,
            Resultat = prestation.ResultatComparaison,
            ValeurPreconisee = prestation.ValeurPreconisee,
            ValeurProposee = prestation.ValeurProposee,
            DesignationPrestation = prestation.DesignationPrestation,
            DesignationResultat = (prestation.ResultatComparaison) ? "OK ✔" : "KO ✘"
        }).ToList();

        return Json(diplayListeResultats.ToDataSourceResult(request, c => new
        {
            c.CategoriePrestation,
            c.CCN,
            c.IdentifiantAccord,
            c.DesignationPrestation,
            c.Resultat,
            c.DesignationResultat,
            c.ValeurPreconisee,
            c.ValeurProposee
        }), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: some screenshots would help understanding the problem I guess. All the Selection options you have are the default ones, so simply having `.Selectable()` would be the same. What is your exact problem tho?

Comment: I know it would be great, my problem is that my information come from a mongo database. And they are not displaying inside my grid !

Comment: Do you see your information in your controller method?

Comment: Yes i see them. Also my id contains the good one

Comment: How is the data being returned back to the grid? Assuming you are hitting the controller which is reading the data.

Comment: It's not hitting the control, i have a break point on it but nothing happens. Don't know why. I checked my route and it seems to be good.

Comment: Ok. so can you post the signature of the `read` controller. In this section `"THISISCONFIDENTIAL", "Comparaison", new { identifiantResultatsComparaison }` what is this **new identifiantResultatsComparaison** declaration meant to be doing? Are you trying to pass something back to your read controller?

Comment: I posted the THISISCONFIDENTIAL

Comment: did you check the http traffic ? maybe a typo in action/controller name?

Comment: yes the type is good ! How can i check the http traffic ? What do you mean ?

Comment: Do you have a really big ammount of data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. Thanks for posting the signature for the read controller. This helps a lot.

All you need to do is make a simple change to the read method on your grid from:

```
.Read(reader => reader.Action("THISISCONFIDENTIAL", "Comparaison", new { identifiantResultatsComparaison }))
```

to

```
.Read(reader => reader.Action("THISISCONFIDENTIAL", "Comparaison").Data("identifiantResultatsComparaison"))
```

By declaring the read function like this it tells the read action to grab the additional data from your **identifiantResultatsComparaison** javascript function.

Then have a function that returns your string back like so:

```
function identifiantResultatsComparaison(){
   var mystringValue = '';
  //do something here 

 return { identifiantResultatsComparaison: mystringValue }
}
```

Hopefully this is clear what you need to do but if not I will expand the answer with updates for you.

Comment: This isn't working for me, the function isn't called. Alert didn't trigger. Don't know why

Comment: so if you have a look at the dev tools of your browser do you see anything in the console throwing an error?

Comment: yes i've got this GET http://localhost:51665/Scripts/kendo.all.min.js 
LancerComparaison:40 GET http://localhost:51665/Scripts/kendo.fr-FR.js

Comment: and this LancerComparaison:43 GET http://localhost:51665/Scripts/globalize.culture.fr-FR.js 
LancerComparaison:42 GET http://localhost:51665/Scripts/globalize.js 404 (Not Found)
LancerComparaison:47 GET http://localhost:51665/Content/js/modernizr.js 
LancerComparaison:83 Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).kendoGrid is not a function(anonymous function) @ LancerComparaison:83c @ jquery-1.9.1.min.js:3p.fireWith @ jquery-1.9.1.min.js:3b.extend.ready @ jquery-1.9.1.min.js:3H @ jquery-1.9.1.min.js:3

Comment: If you are getting not found errors then this would explain why you are getting nothing back/working as expected. Have you checked that the Kendo.all.min.js file exists in the project at the location that is being called? If you check and ensure these script files are included in your project then everything should start working for you correctly.

Comment: Yeah i'm looking at this right now, can't believe i didn't checked that before ! Will telle you if it works, thanks.

Comment: great stuff. Glad it helped.